# Int16 to Byte array wrong array order swift 4

Tags: swift4

i am trying to convert a Int16 into [UInt8] like that:

```
var track:Int16 = 4
let trackData = Data(bytes: &track, count: 2)
```

but the result is

```
[4, 0]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get

```
[0, 4]
```

So when I do :

```
let value = Int16(bigEndian: trackData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
```

I would get **4** instead of **1024**

Comment: `let value = Int16(...).byteSwapped`, maybe... that would make it `4`.

Comment: that exactly the kind of cool function. I will gladly accepted it as Correct!

Comment: I made it as an answer... not much but does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not much a rocket-science but `byteSwapped` may do the job for you, like:

```
let value = Int16(bigEndian: trackData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }).byteSwapped
```

that would make the value `4` in your case.

---

***NOTE:*** even Apple Docs does not say too much about this property (kinda self explanatory, to be honest), so just for the sake of completion, here comes the reference of [`byteSwapped`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1540248-byteswapped).